# Parse stack to second view

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

Im creating a RPN calculator in swift. I need help to the code to view all my calculations when the tape button is pressed to segue to the secondVC. When the tape button is pressed it will display the calculations entered.The functionality in the second view controller. Im knew to programming. I have implemented `prepareforsegue` in my first VC. I do not know how to pass the stack to `numberOfRowsInSection`

Calculator engine

```
class CalculatorEngine :NSObject

{

    var operandStack = Array<Double>()

    func updatestackWithValue(value: Double)
    {
        self.operandStack.append(value)
    }


    func operate(operation: String) ->Double
    {

        switch operation
        {
        case "×":
            if operandStack.count >= 2
        {
        return self.operandStack.removeLast() * self.operandStack.removeLast()
```

---

Second View

```
class SecondVCViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var array = [""]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->  UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]

    return cell
```

Comment: I can see a array. But I do not know how to display the stack of calculations

Comment: Have you implemented `prepareForSegue` in your first VC? It needs to pass the stack to second VC so that `numberOfRowsInSection` (etc) can use it rather than the current code using `array`.

Comment: I have implemented prepareforsegue in my first VC. I do not know how to pass the stack to numberofrowsinsection

Comment: In `prepareForSegue`, if you can cast destinationController as `SecondVCViewController`, then you can set a variable in it. This is how you pass data from one VC to another.